# Shell program to count the number of files in the current directory?

Tags: shell

How do you create a variable that is equal to the number of files in the current directory?

I currently have this.

```
x = ls -1 | wc -l

echo x
```

I feel like this should be really straightforward, but it just says "x not found."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work

```
x=`ls -l|wc -l`
echo $x
```